# How to return response after async call is finished?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I have some express.js app and I have a "Pay" button in my UI.

When I click on it, I want the server to call the checkout API of Stripe and then return a response only when I get the response from the API call (card can be expired, for example).

I know it's a bad practice, but how can my response wait till the async call finishes?

And what's the right way to do such call in express.js?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is preventing you from doing a classic AJAX call and acting once you have a answer?

Comment: Surely the Strip API provides callbacks which you can hook into to send the response?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, mind you I'm not too experienced in express.js, but in js you use functional programming.

```
some_api_call(params)
   .then(isSuccessfulCallback)
   .then(getResponse)
   .catch(e => {
       console.warn(e);
   });
```